# Disk Cleanup Logs

Tags: windows, powershell, logging

I have been trying to find a way to create a log for Disk Cleanup. I want to be able to record what was cleaned and when it was cleaned. I run disk cleanup using a powershell script and that script is run as a scheduled task. I want the logs to be able to verify what was cleaned and when. Is there any way to create logs via powershell for disk cleanup? I looked up online and read that disk cleanup wasn't designed to make logs. I just want to verify whether or not this is true.

`cleanmgr.exe /d C: /VERYLOWDISK`

This is my script/command

Comment: See this [answer from MS](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disk-cleanup-log-results/43975546-eb16-4440-ad27-826310d3f448?tab=AllReplies#tabs) Your script should define `what categories` to clean, otherwise there is no log on details.

Comment: @LotPings so if I add `sageset` and `sagerun`, it should log it?

Comment: Other than doing a complete compare before/after this is IMO the only thing you can do.

Comment: @LotPings OK. If I add this to my script, where would the logs be found?

Comment: I don't know **your** script, a quick search for event log didn't turn up much, just this [quite technical article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/lwef/disk-cleanup)

Comment: @LotPings I read the article and still isn't clear how I would log the actions of disk cleanup. As for my script(not really a script,more like one-line), it's pretty simple. `cleanmgr.exe /d C: /VERYLOWDISK`